# Html.Beginform is not postback to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make Login Page in mvc4 using visual studio 2012 but I am receiving an issue here.

Issue is that when I press the Login button it just refresh the page and show again login page instead of User Login.

My code is here :

*Login View*

```
 @model onlinebookstore.entityframwork.customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>
<div style="background-color:brown;">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Account",FormMethod.Post)){

    @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.user_id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.user_id)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password);
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password);

    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit" value="Login" />
    }
</div>
```

*Account Controller*

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();

        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(onlinebookstore.entityframwork.customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                       onlinebookstore.entityframwork.onlinebookstoreEntities db = new onlinebookstoreEntities();
                       var v = db.customers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.user_id == customer.user_id && u.password == customer.password);
                        if (v != null)
                            {
                            Session["userid"] = v.user_id.ToString();
                            Session["firstname"] = v.first_name.ToString();
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
                        }


            }
            return View(customer);
        }
```

Before sometime this code is working fine but now it create serious issue for me help me please.

Thanks From Rizwan

Comment: It look like ModelState is not valid. Put a breakpoint in your action method and check

Comment: Your code is correct...when u post data by clicking on submit button might be ur modalstate is not valid so u can check the error with the help of breakpoint or just remove modalstate.isvalid() from ur code.

Comment: Thanks Kartikeya Khosla, i remove the modalstate.isvalid() and now my code works fine. Muhammad Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

check if your ModelState.Isvalid is true or false .